# IntelliJ, deploy on local Tomcat doesn't work, shows 404 error

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have the following settings, when artifact, context, Tomcat, .etc looks normal,  (screenshots), when I hit the Run button, I also see in the Output screen that Tomcat is started and the artifact is deployed, but the web page started at http://localhost:8080/ shows an 404 error.

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

[image]
[image]

```
C:\Tomcat7\bin\catalina.bat run
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\Tung\.IntelliJIdea11\system\tomcat\Unnamed_pinbike-express"
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.27 using APR version 1.4.6.
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Tomcat7"
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Tomcat7\temp"
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Tomcat7\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Tomcat7\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1d 5 Feb 2013)
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1154 ms
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.39
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\Tung\.IntelliJIdea11\system\tomcat\Unnamed_pinbike-express\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:34 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\Tung\.IntelliJIdea11\system\tomcat\Unnamed_pinbike-express\work\Catalina\localhost\_\WEB-INF\lib\el-api-1.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:34 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\Tung\.IntelliJIdea11\system\tomcat\Unnamed_pinbike-express\work\Catalina\localhost\_\WEB-INF\lib\jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:35 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\Tung\.IntelliJIdea11\system\tomcat\Unnamed_pinbike-express\work\Catalina\localhost\_\WEB-INF\lib\jboss-javaee-all-7.0-1.0.0.Final.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:35 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\Tung\.IntelliJIdea11\system\tomcat\Unnamed_pinbike-express\work\Catalina\localhost\_\WEB-INF\lib\jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ConfigurationBootstrap).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:46 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [957] milliseconds.
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:46 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:46 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Apr 08, 2016 7:36:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 13478 ms
Connected to server
```

Comment: Do you use Maven or Gradle to build your project? Could you set the javaee, servlet and el dependencies to scope "provided" and then try again?

Comment: Have you tried going to `Project Structure -> Artifacts -> Available Elements` and then right click on them and putting them into `WEB-INF` ?